# So I'm trying a buffer overflow program and i need to execute this code to review an address but i keep getting this error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main (){
         char* shell = getenv("MYSHELL"); 
         if (shell) 
                printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)shell); 

}
```

```
shell.c: In function ‘main’:
shell.c:7:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
    7 |    printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)shell);
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: `warning:` != `error:`.

Comment: It is not a spurious warning. If `shell` were, say, "sh", then that is `{'s','h','\0'}`, say `unsigned == uint32_t`, that would be out-of-bounds. Maybe `memcpy` would be good? What are you _trying_ to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's a warning, not an error. The compiler will still allow you to compile your program when it has warnings (though many programmers would advise fixing those warnings), but if you get a compiler *error* your code will not compile at all.

The reason for the warning is that `char*` is a pointer type, which on x64 architectures is essentially a 64-bit integer. `int`, and by extension `unsigned int`, is a 32-bit integer. If you want to silence the error, you *could* cast to `unsigned long` instead (and change the `%x` to `%lx`), but there's a much easier way. There is a format specifier for pointers, `%p`, which you can simply use with any pointer.

So if you want to silence the warning I'd recommend changing your print statement to `printf("%p\n", shell);`